# Why is Windows.h required for the use of OpenGL functions?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, cross-platform

I am working on an app that uses OpenGL to make a simple game. Just starting to learn OpenGL. Why, in the code snippet below, do I need `<Windows.h>` to recognise `GLuint vao`? Removing the include causes an error.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

int main() {
    GLuint vao;
}
```

I get 868 errors when I remove the include `<Windows.h>`. Errors like `'APIENTRY': this use of 'void' is not valid`, `int APIENTRY: redefinition`, `int WINGDIAPI: redefinition` and honestly a lot more.

I am developing on Windows, but this would automatically mean cross-platform is impossible without some external toolkit/library like GLEW, GLUT etc.? I know they are strongly advised but for reasons, I cannot use them.

Also, does that mean I need to include `<Windows.h>` in every file where I use OpenGL functions? That would not make very good practice, I think.

Comment: Yes, you have to include Windows.h on windows before GL.h. I'm not sure how much that collides with cross-platform, you need to open an OpenGL context, and that is platform specific anyway (Windows wgl, X-Server: glx). OS components (like window handling) are almost never going to be platform independent.

Comment: Please show the error output.

Comment: The error output is 868 errors... Things like `APIENTRY: this use of 'void' is not valid`, `int APIENTRY: redefinition`, `int WINGDIAPI: redefinition`.

Comment: To elaborate a little bit more: Your problem actually isn't the definition of GLuint, because that's defined in gl.h. But all methods defined in gl.h require the `WINGDIAPI` macro to be defined for dll importing, and that is defined in wingdi.h (which is included by Windows.h). Same for the `APIENTRY` (from minwindef.h)

Comment: Right, meaning I have to include `<Windows.h>` in every file that uses OpenGL functions? This is bad practice, am I incorrect? Might have something to do with my project/class structure and might be a whole different issue all around.

Comment: A C or C++ compiler is a single-pass compiler. Every symbol needs to be known at the time it is being used. That's a property C and C++' compilation model and you cannot change that. I suppose what's really wrong here is the expectation to be able to write platform-agnostic OpenGL code. At some point the library has to interact with the OS, and those interactions aren't standardized.

Comment: Instead of including both windows.h and gl.h in all places, you can write your own include file that includes the other two files. My feeling is that what you are trying to do is basically rewrite the platform independent libraries (glfw, glew) that already do what you are trying to do by abstracting the OS specific parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, including Windows.h before including GL.h is required.

But the actual problem is not the definition of `GLuint` which is defined in GL.h, but that all methods defined in `GL.h` require the definition of the `WINGDIAPI` and the `APIENTRY` macro. `WINGDIAPI` tells the compiler that the method has to be loaded from a dll (which is per-se Window specific) and is defined in wingdi.h. `APIENTRY` is defined in minwindef.h. Both are both included by Windows.h.

About cross-platform: The problem is that while the OpenGL API is (in general) platform independent, the OpenGL implementation as well as OpenGL context handling is not. Different systems do not even use the same OpenGL header file. MacOS, for example, uses `OpenGL/gl.h` while Windows uses `GL/gl.h`.
Other example, a OpenGL context is created on Windows through the wgl API while some other systems use glx. If you want to develop cross-platform, you either need to abstract all of that yourself, or you use one of the libraries (glfw, glew) that already do that for you.